# How to print a whole webpage in A4 Size Paper using asp.net / vb.net on button click event?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to print a whole webpage in A4 Size Paper using asp.net / vb.net on button click event ?

I wanna print the Whole DIV tag and all the controls inside it ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to set up a print.css file to tell the page how to render on print alternatively you wish to take the approach I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262143/best-way-to-print-in-asp-net)